# gdb outputs std error

Tags: c++, gdb

gdb is giving me the following

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x000001efa0f31eea in kill () at <stdin>:2
2       <stdin>: No such file or directory.
        in <stdin>
(gdb) where
#0  0x000001efa0f31eea in kill () at <stdin>:2
#1  0x000001efa0f986ca in abort () at /usr/src/lib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:70
#2  0x000001efa8473e71 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at /usr/obj/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:50
#3  0x000001efa8471ba8 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0xf3
) at /usr/obj/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:40
#4  0x000001efa8471bf3 in std::terminate () at /usr/obj/gcc-4.7.2/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:50
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 23, offset = 133635)
        has children: FALSE
        attributes:
                DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_strp) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module /usr/local/lib/libestdc++.so.15.0]
```

I am working on openbsd 5.3 has anyone come across this issue?

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {

  try {
    throw 10;

  }catch (...) {

    std::cout<<"thrown"<<std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

This is enough to cause the problem

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621461/weird-gdb-message-when-debugging-c-program

Comment: GNU gdb 6.3
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "amd64-unknown-openbsd5.3". I am only using gdb because there are exceptions which I cannot catch at all in libraries that are not my own

Comment: Your `main` function ends without returning anything. This may do something unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that but it is not causing the issue. I just ran the same test with the return in place, and the same behaviour was displayed. I am looking into getting an new version of gdb and maybe gcc

Comment: With the new version 7.5.1 of gdb which on openbsd is egdb I no longer get the dwarf errors but I still get                          2       <stdin>: No such file or directory. any ideas ? I can provide full stack trace if someone wants to see it

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error but I can't get a stack trace... gdb does simply throw a Dwarf Error.  Or does it toss a Dwarf Error, anyway making the error difficult to debug.

Comment: @Core what os are you working on ?

Comment: @gda2004 - it is a corporate Linux env where they have a clever way of allowing multiple versions of tools to coexist.  So as it turns out my environment was pointing to an old gdb that was incompatible.