# DW_TAG unspecified type on nullptr?

Tags: c++11, dwarf, gcc7

We have an application that is compiled with a recent version of gcc (g++-7.2)
Unfortunately, the production server is quite old and has a really old version of gdb (6.5.25-el5rh)

It is difficult to debug the software on site, because `gdb` does not show the backtrace with core file.
Opening a core file with gdb leads to this message :

```
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.5-25.el5rh)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-redhat-linux-gnu"...Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".


warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Erreur d'entrée/sortie.
[...]
Reading symbols from /lib/libcrypt.so.1...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libcrypt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_files.so.2...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_files.so.2
Core was generated by `[binary_filename]'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 218, offset = 2719370)
        has children: FALSE
        attributes:
                DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_strp) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module [path_to_binary]]
```

I found on http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=C%2B%2B0x:_Null_pointer that `nullptr` can be translated to `DW_TAG_unspecified_type`.

Is `nullptr` the problem with this old version of gdb ? Is it possible to ask gcc to avoid generating dwarf information for nullptr ?

Precisions:

- We cannot realistically update the gdb version neither deploy our own version of gdb
- We are dependant on having a recent version of gcc (>= C++11), so downgrade of gcc is not desirable

`[local_installation]/generated/bin/g++ -v` :

```
    COLLECT_GCC=./g++
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=[local_installation]/generated/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
    Cible : i686-pc-linux-gnu
    Configuré avec: [local_installation]/gcc-7.2.0/configure --prefix=[local_installation]/generated --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi --with-dwarf2 --enable-cxx-flags=-gdwarf-2
    Modèle de thread: posix
    gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC)
```

`CXXFLAGS`:

```
-pipe -fpermissive -Wshadow -Wextra -Wundef -Wno-deprecated-declarations -std=gnu++17 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf $(INCLUDES) -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
```

Regards

Comment: Why can't you deploy your own GDB? It's just one binary.

Comment: It will need negociation. They have a special way of deploying binaries and having multiples binaries might mess up their deployment process. I'll probably ask that, showing the benefits of this approach.

Comment: So, you can't just put a binary in the home directory, where it won't appear on any PATH or interfere with anything?

Comment: Separate question: does the machine have `gdbserver` installed?

Comment: There is one installed.

Comment: Further research lead me to https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html where they say that unwind information might not be in dwarf2. This question might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621461/weird-gdb-message-when-debugging-c-program/10657175