# gcc 4.7.3 and gdb 7.6 on Mac - strange stepping problems

Tags: c++11, gdb, osx-lion, macports, gcc4.7

I recently installed **GCC 4.7.3** and **GDB 7.6** on my OS X 10.7 system via MacPorts to be able to compile C++11 code. I cannot use Apple's selfmade clang++ and gdb since it doesn't allow me to debug standard template library code properly (for example, if I dereference a list iterator, the program crashes).

Now, with the new GCC / GDB combination I have some weird problems with stepping into functions. Take this minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    virtual void testMethod() {
        printf("test in A\n");
    }
};

void test(A &a) {
    printf("asdf\n");
    a.testMethod(); // here, stepping works with -std=c++11
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.testMethod();
    test(a);
    a.testMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile the code with `g++ -O0 -ggdb test.cpp`, GDB does not step into `A::testMethod` at all. I can set a breakpoint by specifying the code line inside `A::testMethod`, but not by specifying the method name (`b A::testMethod()`).

More strangely, if I compile with `g++ -O0 -ggdb -std=c++11 test.cpp`, GDB steps into testMethod if called from `void test()`. From the main, stepping still doesn't work. However, now, I can set a breakpoint by specifying just the method name.

Further, as soon as I start the program in GDB, I get GDB warnings, as described in related questions. These warnings appear regardless of whether I specify `-std=c++11` or not.

```
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/./gcc/libgcc_eh.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/../src/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/../src/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a"
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-debug_list-2.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-debug_list.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-thread-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc49/libstdcxx-devel/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/_muldi3_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/addtf3_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/darwin-64_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/divtf3_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/emutls_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/enable-execute-stack_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/eqtf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/extenddftf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/extendsftf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/extendxftf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixtfdi_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixtfsi_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixtfti_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixunstfdi_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixunstfsi_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/fixunstfti_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floatditf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floatsitf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floattitf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floatunditf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floatunsitf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/floatuntitf_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/getf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/letf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/multf3_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/negtf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/subtf3_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/trunctfdf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/trunctfsf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/trunctfxf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/unordtf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/unwind-c_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde-darwin_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc47/gcc47/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libgcc/unwind-dw2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

I am aware of the following questions:
    [Debugging Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430972/debugging-problems-with-macports-gcc-on-os-x?lq=1),
    [Weird GDB messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621461/weird-gdb-message-when-debugging-c-program/10657175),
    [GDB error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592521/gdb-error-message-gcc-4-7-from-macports),
    [GDB fails on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050257/gdb-fails-on-mountain-lion),
yet they didn't help me. Specifying `-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf` does not help either.

-EDIT-
The output of `nm` is the same in both cases:

```
0000000100001068 s GCC_except_table0
00000001000010c0 S _NXArgc
00000001000010c8 S _NXArgv
                 U __Unwind_Resume
0000000100000e34 T __Z4testR1A
0000000100000eae T __ZN1A10testMethodEv
00000001000010b0 S __ZTI1A
0000000100000f1d S __ZTS1A
0000000100001090 S __ZTV1A
                 U __ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
00000001000010d8 S ___progname
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
00000001000010d0 S _environ
                 U _exit
0000000100000e61 T _main
                 U _puts
0000000100001000 s _pvars
                 U dyld_stub_binder
0000000100000df8 T start
```

Has anyone managed to get GCC 4.7 and some appropriate debugger working on OS X Lion?

Comment: did find a solution? I am experiencing very similar problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581645/gdb-7-7-does-not-step-in-on-os-x-mavericks-with-gcc4-7-3-macports)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling like this....It is working fine....
Could you just try with -g option alone?

E.g: g++ -g test.cpp -o test

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help. The result is the same as if compiling with -ggdb. How did you install GCC/GDB?

Comment: I'm sorry....I tried ur code in GCC 4.5.3 for CYGWIN. did you try nm  command on the binary file to see if the symbols exist?

Comment: I added the `nm` output to the question. I'm not very familiar with `nm`, however, I think the symbols are present. At least, GDB tab-completes them. Also, I don't think it's a general GCC/GDB problem, more a problem on Mac. On Ubuntu, everything works fine.